# ActiveX Temporarily being Disable

Tags: activex, web

I have a website where I use flash and activeX.  The activeX renders on top of the flash and hence the flash is not visible.  I just need to temporarily disable the Active X until the user clicks or goes to another section of the page.

Any help or advice would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hide the active X by using code.. and later you can resume it in your desired section.

Try something like this, You might have to add more `<br>` tags in the `divWithMyActiveXControlFiller <div>` tag to make up for the size of the `divWithMyActiveXControl` when it is hidden.

```
 <div>
 <div id="divWithMyActiveXControl" style="display:">
    </div>
 <div id="divWithMyActiveXControlFiller" style="display:none">
 <br><br>
 </div>
 </div>
```

To hide:

```
 document.getElementById('divWithMyActiveXControl').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('divWithMyActiveXControlFiller').style.display = '';
```

To show:

```
 document.getElementById('divWithMyActiveXControl').style.display = '';
 document.getElementById('divWithMyActiveXControlFiller').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: if I hide it will it be visible?